# Tkinter two windows OptionMenu issue

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter.optionmenu

File one.py

```
from tkinter import *
import two

root = Tk()
button = Button(text='Click me', command=two.action)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

File two.py

```
from tkinter import *
def action():

    two = Tk()

    list = [1, 2, 3]
    clicked = StringVar()
    clicked.set("Please choose PLC")
    Label(two, text="Choose PLC ", width=15, anchor='w').grid(row=0, column=0)
    drop = OptionMenu(two, clicked, *list)
    drop.config(fg='#777', width=15, height=1)
    drop.grid(row=0, column=1)

    two.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    action()
```

f I run two.py by itself I can see a default value at OptionMenu and the one I chose as well. If I ran two.py from one.py the OptionMenu box is empty. Any ideas where is an error?

Comment: This is probably caused by having multiple instances of Tk. There can only be one instance of Tk in a program. I would recommend changing `two = Tk()` to `two = Toplevel()`. Toplevel windows work the same as Tk windows, but don't cause problems.

Comment: Thanks Henry, I knew that would be some sintax issue. Thats solved the problem.